# How do you receive a url parameter with a spring controller mapping

Tags: spring-mvc

This issue seems trivial, but I can't get it to work properly.  I'm calling my Spring controller mapping with jquery ajax.  The value for someAttr is always empty string regardless of the value in the url.  Please help me determine why.

-URL called

```
http://localhost:8080/sitename/controllerLevelMapping/1?someAttr=6
```

-Controller Mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/{someID}"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody int getAttr(@PathVariable(value="someID") final String id, 
        @ModelAttribute(value="someAttr") String someAttr) {
    //I hit some code here but the value for the ModelAttribute 'someAttr' is empty string.  The value for id is correctly set to "1".
}
```

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You should be using `@RequestParam` instead of `@ModelAttribute`, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping("/{someID}")
public @ResponseBody int getAttr(@PathVariable(value="someID") String id, 
                                 @RequestParam String someAttr) {
}
```

You can even omit `@RequestParam` altogether if you choose, and Spring will assume that's what it is:

```
@RequestMapping("/{someID}")
public @ResponseBody int getAttr(@PathVariable(value="someID") String id, 
                                 String someAttr) {
}
```

Comment: In case anyone else is also looking for the official documentation for `@RequestParam`, here it is: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html

Comment: For people trying to add two methods for one endpoint (one with params and one without) be sure to use the params field on the `@RequestMapping` annotation otherwise Spring will complain.

Answer (score 34):

You have a lot of variants for using `@RequestParam` with additional optional elements, e.g.

```
@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "someValue", value="someAttr") String someAttr
```

If you don't put `required = false` - param will be required by default.

`defaultValue = "someValue"` - the default value to use as a fallback when the request parameter is not provided or has an empty value.

If request and method param are the same - you don't need `value = "someAttr"`