# How to create a custom POST request service in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, service, resources

I have a simple service that does that:

```
packlightApp.factory('Hike', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('app/rest/hikes/:id', {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': { method: 'GET'},

        });
    }]);
```

I want to add a new method that send an array to my backend in order to save it. I don't know what would be the right syntax for my usecase and how I can catch it in my backend. The backend is coded in Java. For example (case of simple a POST request):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/hikes",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = "application/json")
    public void create(@RequestBody HikeDto hikedto) {...}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: ng-resource already have method to save array of data - $save.

Answer (score 0):

You can use de 'save' method from [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

```
app.controller('postCtrl', function($scope, Hike) {
    var objectArray = [{data: 1}, {data: 2}];
    Hike.save({id: 'yourId'}, objectArray, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        // Do things on success.
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. What would be the signature of my java method that will intercept the request in the backend? If i create the same method with an aditional parameter in the signature, my server wont start.

Comment: You can refer to this question, they are trying to solve something similar in Java [RequestMapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021084/how-do-you-receive-a-url-parameter-with-a-spring-controller-mapping). Tell me if the angular part worked.

Comment: when I try your link's solution I m getting a Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found.