# Create regex which will match to all requests in Spring

Tags: java, regex, spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{path:[^\\.]*}")
```

This regex catch only those requests which looks like: `http://localhost:8091/history`. How to change it into `regex` which will catch more specific requests like e.g. `http://localhost:8091/history/blabla`, `http://localhost:8091/history/1` ?

Unfortunately `@RequestMapping(value = "/**")` doesn't work at all.

Comment: It looks like you want to match a parameter. Take a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021084/how-do-you-receive-a-url-parameter-with-a-spring-controller-mapping

Comment: No I don’t want to match the parameter. I want to match all characters after ‘/‘ without dot at the first place

Comment: You may try: `@RequestMapping("/*/*")`

Comment: @YCF_L - `Illegal character escaping`
@anubhava - it wokrs but in only examples like `http://localhost:8091/history/3` so there are two "parameters". And what about when I'd like to provide one,three or infinity this paremeters?

Comment: It also doesn’t work. I have tried this already

Comment: I know but after your response I also tried that one solution

Comment: Nope..nothing happens