# Spring security how to properly apply filter to get param from URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In spring security I need to have custom authentication with param from site that user trying to get access, for example:

User trying to access:

```
 myapp.com/res?param=value
```

In authentication process I need this `value` from param, how can I get this?

Also I have custom `UserDetailsService` where I need this `param`.

I was trying something like this:

```
 public class MyFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {


@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain arg2)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) arg0;
    System.out.println("\n\n"+request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length()) +"\n\n");
    super.doFilter(arg0, arg1, arg2);
     }
 }
```

Which I apllied:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.addFilterAfter(
              new MyFilter(),  BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);    

    http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .and()
    .httpBasic();       
}
```

This filter print out the url with my param but how Can I provide this in my custom `UserDetailsService`? Also I'm not sure this filter is properly.

I use **spring-security 5.0.0** with **spring 5.0.2**

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how Can I provide this in my custom `UserDetailsService`?

By using `Spring` built-in request handlers.

```
@RestController
public class UserDetailService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/res", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getRes(
       @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "value", value="param") final String param) {

         // param contains the value of the parameter in the URL

    }
}
```

More on this [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021084/how-do-you-receive-a-url-parameter-with-a-spring-controller-mapping) and [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping).

---

You should use the `filter` only to validate the requests and block them if needed.

All business logic should be implemented in the `@Controller` and `@Service` classes.