# How to retrieve data in HTTP GET method using query string/parameter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, get

```
URL : http://X.X.X.X/APPLICATION/abc?a=1
```

Is my URL correct?

JAVA Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc?", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView page (@RequestParam(value = "a") String a) {
...
Code Logic
...
}
```

Am I handling it correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021084/how-do-you-receive-a-url-parameter-with-a-spring-controller-mapping ?

Comment: Do you have any other endpoints under http://X.X.X.X/APPLICATION ? Is the application successfully deployed under the contest 'APPLICATION'?

Comment: Endpoints will be like below
/X.X.X.X/APPLICATION/abc?a=1....
/X.X.X.X/APPLICATION/bbb.....
/X.X.X.X/APPLICATION/ccc....

Answer (score 0):

Remove the question mark after abc.

```
value = "/abc"
```

Comment: I did, it says "The server has not found anything matching the requested URI"

Comment: Shall I go with - value = "/APPLICATION/abc"

Comment: Yes because you don't have to give ? Exclusively.

Comment: Still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

this is how I am handling the url params. I have also attached the test code below to make it easier to understand.

Here's my controller

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/APPLICATION")
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/abc")
    public @ResponseBody String getAbc(@RequestParam String a) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

And here's the test code

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;


@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetParamFromUrl() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/APPLICATION/abc?a=1"))
                .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("1")));

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/APPLICATION/abc?a=99"))
                .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("99")));
    }

}
```